# Dynamically add label/checkBox-Combo and put code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I have build a dynamically-generated label/checkbox-List.

The label-content gets his content from a list with some application-names. The Checkbox(es) share a single CheckBox_Click-Event, that is triggered when i hit one of the checkboxes. The Problem i got now is, i can't identify which checkbox is clicked. Because i generate the controls i can't put a name through binding behind the controls. I'm not-so-experienced in creating gui's through code. Hope you guys can help me a bit.

```cs
// This part builds my label/combo-List through a FileInfo-List

Fields = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Field>();
foreach (var app in GetPrograms())
{
  Fields.Add(new Field() {Name = app.Name, Length = 100, Required = true});
}
FieldsListBox.ItemsSource = Fields;
```

```cs
// Here i got the Click-Event.. but i can't identify which Checkbox is clicked

private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  CheckBox senderChk =  sender as CheckBox;

  switch (senderChk.Name)
  {
    //case "checkBox1": // do something
    //case "checkBox2": // do something
  }
}
```

```xml
<!-- And finally the xaml-Code, note the Bindings on label and checkbox -->
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="FieldsListBox">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Label>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" Click="CheckBox_Click" Margin="5,0,0,0"></CheckBox>
                    </StackPanel>
```

Because i already have a list of filenames, i thought i can bind the names on the checkboxes, so i know which checkbox was clicked and can manage the right programmname.

Answer (score 0):

You did this to bind the checked propierty to the comboBox.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" ... ></CheckBox>
```

Do the same and Bind the propierty Uid (used to identify controls in WPF) of the combobox like this:

```
<CheckBox ... Uid="{Binding Name}" ... ></CheckBox>
```

and use it in your switch.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. I was curious because when i tried this with "name" i got the error: "MarkupExtensions are not permitted for "Uid" or "Name"... so i didn't even tried it with "Uid"

Comment: This is a workaround since Uid was not meant for that, it is used internally by WPF. If you want to do something like this you should create a custom control with a label and a comboBox

Comment: The `Tag` property is another option for this type of thing. The whole approach could be improved, though: The action that takes place on a change in the check state of a `Field` should be handled by the `Field` object itself, in the setter of its `Checked` property (really, in a method called by the setter). It's cleaner and simpler, and it lets you arbitrarily add new `Field`s without having to go elsewhere to edit a switch statement.